# Microsoft.Owin and Owin, why is there a separate Owin namespace?

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin

As the title says, why is there a separate Owin namespace? Owin just contains IAppBuilder, I don't understand why this couldn't be in Microsoft.Owin along with the other interfaces.

This only reason I can come up with is to decouple Owin from Microsoft to allow the development of independent frameworks that subscribe to Owin, seeing as it's open source and community driven. However, if that is the case (which I believe it is) that seems to me to be a very shallow understanding and doesn't give me a better grasp of why there are two separate name spaces.

Comment: OWIN is an open standard, so it does not belong to Microsoft. The Microsoft.Owin is the implementation of that standard from Microsoft. Hope this explains it all.

Comment: That much I understood. I guess I'm not explaining my confusion very well (dunno why, I must be confused).  But I don't get why there are extension methods in the Microsoft implementation, in particular AppBuilder.Run(...), that aren't in IAppBuilder. Seems like it should be, where's the disconnect between the two?

Comment: If 'Microsoft.Owin' is implementation of Owin interface, then this must be Katana, although Microsoft doesn't use this name in OWIN implementation code base (if i'm not mistaken; why to involve one more fancy 'Katana' word in .NET to bring confusion? IMHO Just name it Microsoft Owin).